# ¿Cómo concatenar el resultado de un IF con el de un select en sql?

Tags: sql, if

Buenas, yo necesito concatenar el resultado de un select con el resultado de una sentecia If-Else que por separado funciona, pero al querer colocarla en medio de la concatenación me dice que tengo un error en el if. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
select(
 (select(LEFT(Ltrim(Rtrim(DescSujeto))+'                                                                                ',80))from LKSujetos a inner join FTImportaciones b on a.IdSujetos = b.IdSujeto and b.IdImportacion=@iteracion)+

(if(select(LEFT(Ltrim(Rtrim(Domicilio))+'                                                                                ',80))
from LkSujetos a inner join FTImportaciones b on a.IdSujetos = b.IdSujeto and b.IdImportacion=1)is null 
select '                                                                                'else
(select(LEFT(Ltrim(Rtrim(Domicilio))+'                                                                                ',80))
from LkSujetos a inner join FTImportaciones b on a.IdSujetos = b.IdSujeto and b.IdImportacion=1))+


(select(RIGHT('00000000000'+Ltrim(Rtrim(CodigoPerPuridica)),11))from LkPaises a inner join LkSujetos b on a.IdPais = b.IdPais inner join FTImportaciones c on b.IdSujetos = c.IdSujeto and c.IdImportacion=@iteracion))
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta  y pongas mas legible las consultas que asi no se entende nada

Comment: Deberias guardar el resultado de cada operación en variables y concatenar esas variables; de la forma que lo indicas no te funcionará.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de concatenar esos resultados sería guardando éstos en variables para que al final puedas concatenar dichos resultados.

Un ejemplo de ello sería algo como esto:

```
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(10)

SET @var1 = (SELECT columna1 FROM tabla1 WHERE columna1 = <filtro1>)
SET @var2 = (SELECT columna2 FROM tabla2 WHERE columna2 = <filtro2>)

SELECT @var1 + @var2
```

Ahora bien, para aplicar esto a una condición `IF` sería de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @var3 VARCHAR(10)

IF(condición)
BEGIN
 SET @var3 = SELECT columna3 FROM tabla3 WHERE columna3 = <filtro3>;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SET @var3 = SELECT otraColumna3 FROM tabla3 WHERE otraColumna3 = <filtro3>;
END
```

Nos comentas si es lo que buscas colega. Saludos

Comment: Declaro una variable @var, pero al querer hacerle el set y poner el código con el If me sigue diciendo que hay un error en el mismo. Pero yo se que esa query sola anda, porque la puedo ejecutar

Comment: Que error te muestra?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.

Comment: Edite la respuesta con un ejemplo para el condicional `IF`. Si te sigue lanzando ese error que mencionas es netamente por un tema de algún carácter mal utilizado, como por ejemplo `SELECT * FROM tabla1 + SELECT * From tabla2`

Comment: Ahi me anda perfecto, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Para eso estamos colega. Feliz código! =)